# atol() v/s. strtol()

Tags: c, strtol

What is the difference between atol() & strtol()?

According to their man pages, they seem to have the same effect as well as matching arguments:

```
long atol(const char *nptr);

long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

In a generalized case, when I don't want to use the `base` argument (I just have decimal numbers), which function should I use?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`strtol` provides you with more flexibility, as it can actually tell you if the whole string was converted to an integer or not. `atol`, when unable to convert the string to a number (like in `atol("help")`), returns 0, which is indistinguishable from `atol("0")`:

```
int main()
{
  int res_help = atol("help");
  int res_zero = atol("0");

  printf("Got from help: %d, from zero: %d\n", res_help, res_zero);
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Got from help: 0, from zero: 0
```

`strtol` will specify, using its `endptr` argument, where the conversion failed.

```
int main()
{
  char* end;
  int res_help = strtol("help", &end, 10);

  if (!*end)
    printf("Converted successfully\n");
  else
    printf("Conversion error, non-convertible part: %s", end);

  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Conversion error, non-convertible part: help
```

Therefore, for any serious programming, I definitely recommend using `strtol`. It's a bit more tricky to use but this has a good reason, as I explained above.

`atol` may be suitable only for very simple and controlled cases.

Comment: I believe in your example, the condition should be `if (!*end)`.  It will be pointing to the null-terminator of the string (if it was all converted) but won't be set to NULL itself.

Comment: Does this same logic apply to the linux kernel function `simple_strtol`? I cannot get the `if (!*end)` condition to evaluate to true, using your exact model.

Comment: This does not handle error related to numbers out of range. For that errno needs to be checked!

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried atol with string "123ABC" and it did give me value 123. so you are right "for any serious programming, I definitely recommend using strtol". :)

Comment: Note that [POSIX 1003.1](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/3p/atol/) does [**not**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atol.html) guarantee that `0` is returned by `atol()` in case of error. Quote: *If the value cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: This does not work when the string is empty (contains only the null terminator). Unless you are willing to accept that it gets converted to 0.

Answer (score 24):

`atol` functionality is a subset of `strtol` functionality, except that `atol` provides you with no usable error handling capabilities. The most prominent problem with `ato...` functions is that they lead to undefined behavior in case of overflow. Note: this is not just a lack of informative feedback in case of an error, this is *undefined behavior*, i.e. generally an unrecoverable failure.

This means that `atol` function (as well as all other `ato..` functions) is pretty much useless for any serious practical purposes. It was a design mistake and its place is on the junkyard of C history. You should use functions from `strto...` group to perform the conversions. They were introduced, among other things, to correct the problems inherent in functions of `ato...` group.

Answer (score 19):

According to the `atoi` man page, it has been deprecated by `strtol`.

```
IMPLEMENTATION NOTES
The atoi() and atoi_l() functions have been deprecated by strtol() and strtol_l() 
and should not be used in new code.
```

Answer (score 6):

In new code I would always use `strtol`. It has error handling and the `endptr` argument allows you to see which part of the string was used.

The C99 standard states about the `ato*` functions:

> Except for the behavior on error,they equivalent to
>
> `atoi: (int)strtol(nptr,(char **)NULL, 10)`
>   `atol: strtol(nptr,(char **)NULL, 10)`
>   `atoll: strtoll(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)`

Answer (score 5):

`atol(str)` is equivalent to

```
strtol(str, (char **)NULL, 10);
```

Use strtol if you want the end pointer (to check whether there are more characters to read or if in fact you have read any at all) or a base other than 10. Otherwise, atol is fine.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, `strtol()` has the added benefit to set the (optional) `endptr` to point to the first character that could not be converted.  If `NULL`, it is ignored.  That way if you're processing a string containing numbers and characters mixed, you could continue.

e.g.,

```
char buf[] = "213982 and the rest";
char *theRest;
long int num = strtol(buf, &theRest, 10);
printf("%ld\n", num);    /* 213982 */
printf("%s\n", theRest); /* " and the rest" */
```

Answer (score 1):

The man page of strtol gives the following:

```
ERRORS
   EINVAL (not in C99) The given base contains an unsupported value.
   ERANGE The resulting value was out of range.
   The implementation may also set errno to EINVAL in case no conversion was performed (no digits seen, and 0 returned).
```

The following code checks for range errors. (Modified Eli's code a bit)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
   errno = 0;
   char* end = 0;
   long res = strtol("83459299999999999K997", &end, 10);

   if(errno != 0)
   {
      printf("Conversion error, %s\n", strerror(errno));
   }
   else if (*end)
   {
      printf("Converted partially: %i, non-convertible part: %s\n", res, end);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Converted successfully: %i\n", res);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is old, the content is not as it is about an integral part of the language.

Other answers fail to emphasize two important detail: Both `atol` and `strl` will do the same thing but `atol` tries to parse only a `base 10` format (signs
and digits) and will give `no error`.

- While `strtol` (and all `strto_` that return integer type) can fetch a number in any base ranging from 2 to 36, all `ato_` functions (atoi, atol) will fetch only base 10.
- Both will return zero (0) if no parse is possible, yet `strtol` can give the location where parse is ended and an error if the number was too big/small.

side note: any `strto_` or `ato_` that returns a decimal number uses base 10, meaning digits and a few other characters to represent a floating-point number.