# Get int value from string C

Tags: c, string, int

Given that I have the following:

```
char str[] = "1524";
int nr;
```

I would like to get the number `1524` in 'nr'.

What's the best way to achieve that in C?

Comment: use the atoi function.

Comment: @Nabla Yes, I did. I corrected. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @OldProgrammer That's correct. Thank you. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: atoi has no error detection

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best with error detection is `strtol()`

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char str[] = "1524";
char *endptr;
errno = 0;
long l = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
if (errno || *endptr != '\0' || str == endptr || l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX) {
  Handle_Error();
}
else {
  nr = l;
}
```

`errno` becomes non-zero when over/underflow occurs.
`*endptr != '\0'` detects extra garbage at the end.
`str != endptr` detects a strings like `""`.
Compare against `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN` needed when `int` and `long` differ in range.
Maybe better to do `if (errno == ERANGE ...`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792663/atol-v-s-strtol/3792676#3792676 provides some pros/cons of `atoi() v strtol()`

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) function:

```
nr = atoi(str);
```

There is also [`atof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) (for `float`s) and [`atol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atol/) (for `long`s)

All of these functions are defined in `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 4):

The standard library call is [`atoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi), though there's also [`strtol()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) which has a couple added features.  1) it lets you specify the numerical base (like base 10), and 2) it returns the pointer to the place in the string where it stopped parsing.

Both are defined in the header `<stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 3):

The [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) function will convert from the string to an integer:

```
// requires including stdlib.h

int nr = atoi(str);
```