# Why there is a underline before wtoi in function _wtoi which ansi version is atoi?

Tags: visual-c++, wchar

Hello！ It is confused me for a long time!

Long long ago , there is only ansi version that is atoi .

And now (it is also long long ago ) there is a wide char version .

But why the wide char version has a uderline('_') before wtoi?

Could any one tell me why? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Because Microsoft put it there — no other reason.  It's their function, so they can do as they like with it; neither `wtoi()` nor `_wtoi()` is standardized except, de facto, by Microsoft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the most part, functions that begin with a leading underscore are implementation additions; they are not part of the C Standard Library.  (There are exceptions, e.g. `_Exit` is part of the C Standard Library, though it is not yet implemented in the Visual C++ implementation.)  Identifiers that begin with a leading underscore are [reserved in the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier), so they are used for nonstandard extensions to avoid conflict with user-defined names.

As for why there is no `wtoi` in the C Standard Library:  By the time wide character functions were added to the C Standard Library, it was understood that the `atoi` interface is flawed because [there is no way to detect whether the conversion succeeded or failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792663/atol-v-s-strtol).

Do not use `atoi` or `_wtoi`.  Instead, use the preferable `strtol` and `wcstol` functions, both of which are part of the C Standard Library.  (There are other similarly-named conversion functions for other types, e.g. `strtof` and `wcstof` to convert to `float` and `strtoull` and `wcstoull` to convert to `unsigned long long`.)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides the functions `_atoi_l, _wtoi, _wtoi_l` as vendor specific extensions. They are not standard C/C++ library functions. They have many such vendor specific functions that have names derived from standard C/C++ library functions.

Comment: Why the standard C/C++ library does not provide the widechar version ?

Comment: @NorSDNorSD Good question. I don't know the answer to that.