# Runtime error using atoi() in C

Tags: c, strtok, atoi

My problem statement was to accept a string of numbers and display the different numbers on screen. So i tried to use `strtok()` to divide the string to different numbers and `atoi()` to convert these to numbers. But I'm getting runtime error.. I have also attached a sample code.

Input

```
1 22 123 89 12 as a string
```

Output

```
1 22 123 89 12 as numbers
```

I need to do mathematical operations on these numbers. So I must convert from integer to string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int i,j;
    char buffer [256];

    char *token;
    const char s[2]= " ";
    fgets (buffer, 256, stdin);

    token=strtok(buffer,s);
    i = atoi (token);
    printf("%d \n",i);
    while (token!=NULL)
                {token=strtok(buffer,s);
                i = atoi (token);
                printf("%d ",i);
                }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `atoi` segfaults on a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: check `token != NULL` before calling `atoi`. Currently you are calling atoi before checking for null.

Answer (score 2):

Besides changing the argument to your `strtok` calls in the loop, you need to change the order in which you call `strtok` and `atoi`. Right now, what if `strtok` in the loop returns `NULL`, which it will do sooner or later?

So instead do e.g.

```
token=strtok(buffer,s);
while (token!=NULL)
{
    i = atoi (token);
    printf("%d ",i);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `token` for NULL before first `atoi()` itself. Alongside, usage of `strtol()` is preferred over `atoi()`.

That said, I think, to serve your purpose,

```
while (token!=NULL)
            {token=strtok(buffer,s);
```

should be

```
while (token!=NULL)
            {token=strtok(NULL,s);
```

Otherwise, you'll end up parsing the input from starting over and over again.

Next, to avoid the `\n` read by `fgets()`, use delimiter string like

```
 char * s = " \n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) of strtok():

The strtok() function parses a string into a sequence of tokens. On the first call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified in str. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, str should be NULL.

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
```

So modify your while loop as follows (Look at the order of `atoi()` and `strtok()` function calls):

```
while (token!=NULL)
{
i = atoi (token);
printf("%d ",i);
token=strtok(NULL,s);
}
```

You can also use [strtol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021725/converting-string-to-integer-c) which is obviously better than [atoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792663/atol-v-s-strtol).